# find index of max from two dimensional time series data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the max value and its location. Following is the example of the programme,

```
fname = dir('*.mat');
nfiles = length(fname);
vals = cell(nfiles,1);

phen = cell(nfiles,1);

for i = 1:nfiles

    vals{i} = load(fname(i).name);
    phen{i} = (vals{i}.phen);
    [M, position] = max(phen{i},[],3);
    clear vals

end
```

After the program is executed, all the position is showing 1. There are total 15 files and M is taking the values of the last file.

How to overcome this prpoblem? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question.

However, at every iteration you are computing the max value and position and overwriting them in the next iteration (i.e. not storing them anywhere). So at the end of the loop `M` and `position` would correspond to the last entry `phen{nfiles}`.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run through your for loop, you are overwriting M with the max from the most recently loaded phen from the dimension of 3.  Since your data is only two dimensional, you probably should be using a dimension of 1 or 2 instead of 3.  Because you are using 3, max is returning 1 to position.  Fix the dimension issue and position should then be the correct value.

What you could do is make M and position the size of nfiles. So instead of

```
[M, position] = max(phen{i},[],3);
```

do

```
%create M and positions arrays here
%ex. M(nfiles) = 0; or a smaller value if your values are negative
%do the same for positions
[M(i), positions(i)] = max(phen{i},[],1); %1 or 2 correction here here!
```

then after your for loop

```
...
end
[maxM, maxMposition] = max(M);
position = positions(maxMposition);
```

Comment: This is not working. Let me probe more and I shall get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, without having your files, I can't give you an exact answer.  The code I provided was not a copy and paste solution, it was just to give you a good starting point on what to modify.